# Why does .Any() not work in this specific XElement extension method?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml, xelement

I made a simple method that returns a string value from a specific node (or returns null if it doesn't exist).

```
private static string getValueIfExist(XElement element, string nodeName)
{    
  return element.Elements(nodeName).Any() ? element.Elements(nodeName).First().Value : null;
}
```

Now I want to use that method as an extension method of XElement:

```
public static string GetValueIfExist(this XElement element, string nodeName)
{
  return element.Elements(nodeName).Any() ? element.Elements(nodeName).First().Value : null;
}
```

But it doesn't compile. For some reason both the Any() and First() are no longer seen as part of IEnumerable. What am I doing wrong? Is there another way to get this specific extension method?

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Have you added the System.Linq namespace?

Comment: Why do you need that extension method? Sounds as if `(string)element.Element(nodeName)` should do. Or `(string)element.Elements(nodeName).FirstOrDefault()`.

Comment: Error I'm geting:
'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' does not contain a definition for 'Any' and no extension method 'Any' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<System.Xml.Linq.XElement>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Yes, I've added System.Linq namespace. I don't really need the extension method (the private method works), but I would have really liked one. The element.Element(nodeName).FirstOrDefault() will fail if no node could be found (hence the .Any() check).

Answer (score 1):

The solution turned out to be very simple ... Jens Kloster was on the right track. I forgot to include the `System.Linq` namespace in my Extensions class. The first time I checked the includes and saw `System.Xml.Linq` included, I thought that was all I needed. But now I realise I needed both namespaces.

I also noticed Visual Studio 2012 doesn't come up with a "Resolve" menu item for this particular case when you right-click on Any().

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your class `static` as well.

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static string GetValueIfExist(this XElement element, string nodeName)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Comment: I know. I'm using the extension method in a separate Extensions class. But if you try the above code, you'll see that Visual Studio starts complaining about missing .Any() and .First() methods.